# Why doesn't homogeneity of linear map follow from additivity?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

As per Wikipedia:

> Let $\mathbf V$ and $\mathbf W$ be vector spaces over the same field $K$. A function $f:V\to W$ is said to be a linear map if for any two vectors $\mathbf u ,\mathbf v \in V$ and any scalar $c \in K$ the following two conditions are satisfied:
>
> $$f(\mathbf {u} +\mathbf {v})=f(\mathbf {u})+f(\mathbf {v})$$ additivity / operation of addition
>
> $$f(c\mathbf {u})=cf(\mathbf {u})$$    homogeneity of degree 1 / operation of scalar multiplication

In the first condition, $f(\mathbf {u} +\mathbf {v})=f(\mathbf {u})+f(\mathbf {v})$ if we set $\mathbf v = \mathbf u$, doesn't it follow that $f(2\mathbf u) = f(\mathbf u + \mathbf u) = 2f(\mathbf u)$? And isn't $f(\mathbf u + \ldots + \mathbf u \text{ (c times)}) = c f(\mathbf u)$? So I'm not sure why they state the homogeneity condition separately.

Comment: Its independent, since $c$ need not be an integer.

Comment: What about $f(\pi u)$?

Comment: One way to get a counter example is to consider $\mathbb R$ as a vector space over $\mathbb Q$ and get $\mathbb Q$-linear maps $\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ which are discontinuos.

Comment: @caffeinemachine : Interesting! I wonder if such a map exists. Do you have one in mind?

Comment: @MPW My point was that you have millions of such maps. Pick a $\mathbb Q$-basis $\mathcal B$ of $\mathbb R$ with $1\in \mathcal B$ and choose a bijection $\mathcal B\to \mathcal B$ with $1\mapsto 1$. This gives you a $\mathbb Q$-linear isomorphism $\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$. Any such linear map obtained this way is discontinuous unless it is the identity map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you can't deduce things like $f(\sqrt{2}u)=\sqrt{2} f(u)$ from additivity only.

Comment: But I think you *can* deduce the corresponding conclusion for *rational* multipliers from additivity alone. (I'm assuming the field $K=\mathbb{R}$, as you have.)

Comment: Indeed, it's true that you have it for all rationals. To get it for all reals, you need something like continuity.