# Linear Map from Additivity alone

Tags: real-analysis, vector-spaces

First off, let me note that I am aware of this post: [Why doesn't homogeneity of linear map follow from additivity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3674815/why-doesnt-homogeneity-of-linear-map-follow-from-additivity)
which asked a similar question to mine, but I am adding enough detail that I think it is worth a new question.

The typical definition for a linear mapping requires two conditions.

$f(x+y) = f(x)+f(y)$

and

$f(kx) = kf(x)$

where $k$ is a scalar and $x$ and $y$ are members of some vector space. My understanding is that this generalizes to a definition using fields, but my experience is in application so I am used to vector spaces. Now, in my experience, one typically works with linear functions when discussing linearity. Consider the following argument:

###################################################################################

Suppose we have that

$f(x+y) = f(x)+f(y)$

for some continuous $f:\mathbb{R}^{D}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{D}$. Note that

$f(Nx) = f(\Sigma_{n=1}^{N}x) = \Sigma_{n=1}^{N}f(x) = Nf(x)$

From here we can also find that

$f(Nx) = f\left( M\left[\frac{N}{M}x\right]\right) = Mf\left( \frac{N}{M}x\right)$

and hence

$Nf(x) = Mf\left( \frac{N}{M}x\right)$

from which it follows that

$\frac{N}{M}f(x) = f\left( \frac{N}{M}x\right)$

so we have

$f(qx) = qf(x)$

for all

$q\in\mathbb{Q}$

. Now, take some arbitrary $r\in\mathbb{R}$ and a sequence $(q_{i})_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ s.t.

$q_{i}\rightarrow r$

it follows that

$f(q_{i}x) - q_{i}f(x)\rightarrow f(rx) - rf(x)$

by continuity. Moreover, since

$f(q_{i}x) - q_{i}f(x) = 0$

for each $i$, we can conclude that

$f(rx) - rf(x) = 0$

or, in other words, that

$f(rx) = rf(x)$

###################################################################################

So for a pretty general setting, linearity would appear to follow from additivity. I therefore find it puzzling that this was never pointed out in my formal education. So, I have two questions.

1. Is this setting not as general as I think? In particular, do mathematicians often consider linearity in discontinuous functions? Edit: and if that is the case, what would be an example?
2. Is it fair to say (and I realize this is more of a soft/opinion question) that for most applications it is fair to think of linearity as coming just from the additivity condition?

Comment: You are able to consider linear actions in places where continuity makes no sense

Comment: @FShrike Interesting. What would be an example of such a setting?

Comment: (non-topologised) Groups, for instance. Or rings without a topology. Or additive categories. Or vector spaces with neither norm nor topology, or linear algebra over less usual fields where there is no dense-subset-of-rationals to appeal to

Comment: I believe a map is called *affine* if it is purely additive, and affine maps are of interest to some subjects of geometry and algebra

Comment: In application all numbers are rational.

Comment: @FShrike If you have any desire, I'd be happy to accept one of these examples as an answer.